# How to change the compression and format settings of images taken in 8k+ 64MP on my Samsung Galaxy S20+ 5G

Tags: applications, settings, camera, samsung-galaxy-s-20, compression

The Camera App natively supports 64MP and I have read that my phone (Samsung Galaxy S20+ 5G) may be able to go even higher.

I'm taking lots of pictures in 64MP and it's great, but I've noticed an issue.

The images appear to be compressed with visible compression artifacts in the lossy jpeg format.

I'd much prefer that that they are stored losslessly when taken and later I can deal with how I want to compress/handle them.

I have not yet found an app or setting that can do this.

Most of the apps and settings I've used to get a RAW image generally work, but none have preserved the capacity to take pictures in 64MP, instead they apply to 4k, which is not what I'm interested in especially.

I've tried the Camera App's Pro Mode, Open Camera, CameraMX and Lightroom. I even tried using a special build of Google's Camera App for my phone that I got from XDA Developers. And CameraMX just crashes at start.

Comment: I looked at the [specs of the Galaxy S20+ 5G](https://www.samsung.com/us/mobile/galaxy-s20-5g/specs/) and I only see two 12 MP, a telephoto 64 MP and a depth camera. If the stock Samsung camera app isn't giving you any larger RAW sizes, it is doubtful such a thing is possible (only Samsung has access to camera drivers and such). See related questions in comments to: [pixel binning vs higher individual pixel size](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/115033/67934)

Comment: Thanks. I originally noticed that one of my images showed a visible grid structure when zoomed in. I assumed this had to do with jpeg compression. Now I look at my 8k images and I don't see that same structure. Interesting...